# vba replace all in column within sections broken by "/"

Tags: vba, excel

So I have some code that goes through a list of names (most are one username per row). A few of the row have multiple names broken up by the "/" character (John Doe / Smith Jr / Some Guy). I use the following code (repeated per name case) in order to modify all names to a proper LDAP name.

```
Worksheets(2).Columns("B").Replace _
What:="*smith*", Replacement:="jsmith", _
SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False

Worksheets(2).Columns("B").Replace _
What:="*Doe*", Replacement:="jdoe", _
SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False
```

This worked for every field that only has a single name entry. Is there a way specify  to remove *John Doe* with the wildcard "*" charcters (some fields may not be spelt correctly etc), but to not modify anything past "/".

Example data

```
John Doe
Abraham Lincoln / john_doe
doe john
doe john / Obiwan
john doe / jsmith / mark mane
john smith / john doe
john does
```

Expected Output

```
jdoe
Abraham Lincoln / jdoe 
jdoe
jdoe / Obiwan
jdoe / joe smith / mark mane
jsmith / jdoe
jdoe
```

What I am receiving

```
jdoe
jdoe
jdoe
jdoe
jdoe
jsmith
jdoe
```

Comment: Hi Blue apologies i'm not entirely understanding your question.  Currently your searching Column 2 for "*Doe*" and you're replacing it with "jdoe".  Now you're looking to locate "*John Doe*" and remove it?

Comment: @StormsEdge I added some sample data to hopefully better illistrustrate what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: No, not without doing cell-wise iteration. You're wildcards are consuming the entire string, `John Doe / Smith Jr / Some Guy` **is** a match for `*Doe*`, and the `Range.Replace` method is going to replace that match, with the specified `"jdoe"` string.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman doesn't work if John Doe is first entry in the cell...

Comment: @ScottHoltzman that is actually a really good idea.

Comment: @DavidZemens True, but I could always throw in a "/" to the beginning of every cell in the row, run the command he is giving, and then remove that first "/"

Comment: @ScottHoltzman If you want to give that as an answer I will gladly accept it :)

Comment: Or you could use Text to Columns and just run the `Replace` method against each column. Lots of ways to accomplish it, but the `Range.Replace` method is kind of clunky sometimes.

Comment: Thank you for the help everyone!

Comment: Add a trailing slash at the *end* of every cell, too. You'll also need to keep the slashes in the `Replacement` value, like `What:="/*Doe*/", Replacement:="/ jdoe /"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`What:="/*Doe*/", Replacement:="/jdoe/"`

And add a trailing `/` to each cell in the range so it catches entries like `some name / john doe`

Comment: Note: Also needs to add the `/` as prefix and suffix to the `Replacement` value., Also needs to add a trailling `/` to each cell in the range, otherwise it won't catch the John Doe in `Abraham Lincoln / John Doe`

Comment: @DavidZemens - thanks. I was going to build a more fully fleshed answer, but the OP seems to be able to handle it. May be worth fleshing out more fully for others though.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I concur, I understood that a prefix & suffix "/" was needed, but other people may miss it when stumbling upon this question

Answer (score 2):

This should also work, and doesn't require prefix/suffix anything. This processes 100K cells in about 6 seconds (per call to the `foo` function).

```
Sub main()
' This is your main procedure and you can specify all _
  of your replacements here on their own line:

Call foo("*Doe*", "jdoe")
Call foo("*Ruth*", "bruth")
Call foo("*Washington*", "gwashington")
' etc...

End Sub

Sub foo(replace, replacement)
Dim rng As Range, cl As Range, vals

Set rng = Worksheets(2).Range("B1:B100000")  'Modify as needed
For Each cl In rng.Cells
    vals = Split(cl.Value, " / ")
    For i = LBound(vals) To UBound(vals)
        If vals(i) Like replace Then
            vals(i) = replacement
        End If
    Next
    cl.Value = Join(vals, " / ")
Next


End Sub
```