# vba what="name" replacement="somethingNew" not working as expected

Tags: vba, excel

Recently had an issue that was resolved and appeard to be working perfectly [vba replace all in column within sections broken by "/"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36317691/vba-replace-all-in-column-within-sections-broken-by/36317984#36317984)

I have been testing various data and ran into an issue that I cannot figure out.

If I have some test-data such as

```
 /   test user / john Streett  /
```

and run the following code

```
Worksheets(1).Columns(Poc).Replace _
What:="/ *street* /", Replacement:="/rstreett/", _
SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False
```

My data comes out as

```
/rstreett/
```

This is not what I am expecting to happen nor what I want to happen. I expect:

```
/   test user /rstreett/
```

Other data such as

```
 /  Test User / maul /  Random User / Third User /
```

With the exact code (names changed)

```
Worksheets(1).Columns(Poc).Replace _
What:="/*maul*/", Replacement:="/dmaul/", _
SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False
```

Data comes out as...

```
 /dmaul/  Random User / Third User /
```

It deletes the "First User"! Not what I have intended at all.
What I expect is:

```
/  Test User /dmaul/  Random User / Third User /
```

I have been trying to figure this out all morning and am completely stuck. If someone could explain the error in my ways it would be greatly appreciated.

WORKAROUND

I have a workaround that gets past the above issue of trying to parse the data. I use `split` in order to split the names to different columns and then modify the data individually in those cells to allow me to use the updated names. Code is below (hopefully no typos but you can get the gist of it.)

```
#Set active sheets
For i = 1 To 8
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(i).Activate

#This portion creates the "/" as a seperator
For Q = 2 To 1000
If Cells(Q, "B").Value <> "" Then
  Cells(Q, "B").Value = "/ " & Cells(Q, "B").Value & " /"
end if

#This portion changes "," to "/" which were used sometimes in my case to split names
Worksheets(i).Columns("B").Replace _
What:=",", Replacement:="/", _
SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False

#Split the names (first into column 1, second into column 2)
#I only need 2 names from all the names that may be in field which is why I only push to 2 columns (24 and 25)
dim Poc = 24
dim addPoc = 25
For Q = 2 To 1000
Dim tokens() As String
    Name = Cells(Q, "B").Value
    tokens = Split(Name, "/")
    If UBound(tokens) > 0 Then Cells(Q, Poc).Value = tokens(1)
    If UBound(tokens) > 1 Then Cells(Q, addPoc).Value = tokens(2)
End If
Next Q

#Now I proceed through the 2 new columns and modify the names
Dim colPoc
For Each colPoc In Array(Poc, addPoc)
  Worksheets(i).Columns(colPoc).Replace _
  What:="*street*", Replacement:="rstreet", _
  SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False

  Worksheets(i).Columns(colPoc).Replace _
  What:=" *maul* ", Replacement:="dmaul", _
  SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False

  Worksheets(i).Columns(colPoc).Replace _
  What:="*test*", Replacement:="tuser", _
  SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False

  #these statements continue to modify all possible names that may be encountered
Next I

#Now I proceed through the 2 new columns and modify the names
```

Comment: **Poc** simple iterates between a few different columns.

Comment: Wildcard * (any character) includes \, so your replacement is "greedy" - it replaces as much text as it can given the pattern.

Comment: @TimWilliams - is regex an alternative that would work? (Scott, yeah I just caught that and deleted my question, sorry :P)

Comment: @BruceWayne to modify names to a shortened nickname `/ test users / super cool / third man /` would equal `/tusers/scool/tman/`. Nicknames are not always based off of a different format that just firstinitialLastName

Comment: @TimWilliams I understand that, I just do not understand why  it is not stopping at "/" as I have specified (or believe I have).

Comment: And why it is only going one direction to which is equally as confusing if it was greedy on both sides.

Comment: @BruceWayne the data then gets parsed to separated fields. this question explains steps after the formatting is done. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36320872/vba-pulling-names-from-fields-using-instr-and-left-right?noredirect=1#comment60295761_36320872

Comment: The replace is technically working correctly.  Starting with the first `/` it finds in a cell, it will remove *all text* from there, until "streett".  Then, the second wildcard will select *all text* after "streett" until the next `/` it finds. It doesn't necessarily know which `/` is the third, fourth,etc. (thanks for the link, I see now).

Comment: If you first replace all instances of "\ " and " \" with "\" then your task would be simpler

Comment: @BruceWayne that makes perfect sense!. It is like a lightbulb went off.  Any thought on how I could rectify this?

Comment: @TimWilliams that is easy enough to do. I had it that way before but added the spaces for troubleshooting.

Comment: In trying to make this a macro, would you be able to expand on how the cell may look? Do you have a list of usernames ("lfay","streett",etc) that you know you'll need to replace? I'm just thinking of a way to prompt the user and ask for what name to find, and the macro will find that name within two `/`, and replace with _____? I could of course ask twice, what's the name to replace, and what's the replacement...but if you *know* what the replacements will be, we can program that in. (Does this question make sense?)

Comment: @BruceWayne I want this to be completely silent. You would run the macro and it would modify the entire row. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36317691/vba-replace-all-in-column-within-sections-broken-by/36317984#36317984 Shows what I am trying to achieve. There is roughly 3k rows with names, and maybe 150 different "nicknames". The names may be "john smith" or "John Smith" or "j smith", so it should have some wildcard ability.

Comment: Currently I have roughly 70 `Worksheets(1).Columns(Poc).Replace _
What:="/*fay*/", Replacement:="/lfay/", _
SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False` statements that are in a massive loop

Comment: I am wondering if this might be easier: Use Split to break the string into an array delimited by "/".  Then loop through the array to make your substitutions, then Join the array using the "/" delimiter to reassemble it.  You can use Trim to remove padding spaces in the array elements for your comparisons too.

Comment: @BruceWayne I believe I have come to a conclusion. I plan to use `split` to separate names into 3 different columns based off "/" seperator (one name per column in a row with a). From here I can run my `replace` statement on the columns (only have to worry about one name). Afterwards I can use the data from the new columns as I need and delete when I no longer need.

Comment: @leowyn I am going to use something similar to yours to split the data into new columns so I can pick and choose how the names are used. I will have to cleanup a bit more which isn't the best, but it should be simple enough to do. Thank you.

Comment: If you get a better version of what you have, would you kindly edit it into your OP? I'm interested in this, it's a fun puzzle.

Comment: @BruceWayne absolutely. Did you want a better question format for how I was previously trying to accomplish this tasks? Or would you like me to add a portion of how I am currently resolving my issue?

Comment: If you have a solution (or are getting closer), I'm interested in that. I'll take a crack at this later this evening, so if you've made any progress, I can work off that :D

Comment: @BruceWayne code is up

Comment: It sounds like you want to be using regular expressions, not wildcards.

Comment: @MacroMan Pretty new to vba (day 4), so not entirely sure of verbiage or how to go about implementing those things.

Comment: @bluerojo regular expressions (RegEx) can be a bit daunting, but if you can master it - it will unlock a whole world of possibilities. It's a very powerful tool to have knowledge of as a developer. VBA has a `Like` operator which uses a small subset of RegEx, might be worth having a look at that when you get a chance and feel more comfortable with the language. One to bear in mind, anyway.

Comment: @MacroMan Thank you very much. I will definitely look into this

Comment: Yeah, regex is what I was thinking too. I'm pretty new to it but this is a great chance to try my skills :p

Comment: Wait - in your code, you replace some `,` with `/`? Why? Are you positive those don't help? Why can't you leave the commas in?

Comment: @BruceWayne I simply did this for readability and I was having `split` split by "/". Not all fields were separated by `,`. Some were by comma, or "/".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it. Call this from your current sub, after your `For Each colPoc In Array(Poc, addPoc)`, remove your `Replaces` and put these lines (I assume `colPoc` is a range, so we need the column it's in):

```
replaceText "maul", "dmaul", colPoc.column
replaceText "Streett", "rstreett", colPoc.column
replaceText "test", "tuser", colPoc.column
```

Then, add this in the same module/sheet your current code is in:

```
Sub replaceText(findString As String, replaceString As String, colPoc As Long)
    Dim replaceStr$, searchStr$, str$, editedStr$
    Dim lastRow&
    Dim cel As Range, rng As Range

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, colPoc).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng = Range(Cells(1, colPoc), Cells(lastRow, colPoc))
    For Each cel In rng
        cel.Select
        str = cel.Value
        editedStr = StrReverse(Replace(StrReverse(str), StrReverse(findString), StrReverse(replaceString), , 1))

        Dim strArray As Variant, finalArray As Variant
        Dim i&, startPos&
        If InStr(1, editedStr, replaceString, vbBinaryCompare) Then
            strArray = Split(editedStr, "/")
            For i = LBound(strArray) To UBound(strArray)
                startPos = InStr(1, strArray(i), replaceString, vbBinaryCompare)
                If startPos Then
                    strArray(i) = Mid(strArray(i), startPos, startPos + Len(replaceString))
                    strArray(i) = Trim(strArray(i))
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i

        finalArray = Join(strArray, "/")
        cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = finalArray
        End If

    Next cel
End Sub
```

...I'm sure someone can help tighten that up (or use RegEx), but I believe that should work.  Here's what it does for me, when I run it with

```
replaceText "maul", "dmaul", 1
replaceText "Streett", "rstreett", 1
```

[image]

I think it's case sensitive, but we can worry about that later...

(Thanks to @leowyn for the `Split/Join` idea! and also [@EngineerToast for the StrReverse idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29477650/4650297))

Comment: I do not have time at this moment to test this, but from looking at this, this would work perfectly to resolve my issue! :). Thank you for your hard-work.